# Entity Framework Core : populating relationship navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Is it possible in .NET 6 with Entity Framework Core 6 to populate the relationship navigation property by setting the foreign key value and then call `SaveChanges`?

I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. Although the other way around works perfectly (if I set the navigation property to the related entity).

Screenshots:

[setting the foreign key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw39q.png)

[after save changes, "department" property still null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlXcu.png)

When trying this, `student.department` remains null after calling `SaveChanges`

```
var student = db.Students.Find(9);
student.departmentId = 1;
db.SaveChanges();
```

While if I do this, the foreign key `student.departmentId` gets populated after calling `SaveChanges`:

```
var student = db.Students.Find(9);
student.department = db.Departments.Find(1);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Try to use the [.Include()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) method when querying the Students entities, to load the Department too.

Comment: @ManuelFabbri tried that...Include only gets related entities while fetching, but its not affecting at all while ur updating a model

Comment: So I guess you should reload the entity from the context after you change the foreign key to the Department.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When trying this student.department remains null after savechanges

Setting the foreign key value doesn't load the related department.  The use case for setting the foreign key directly is typically to *avoid* actually loading the related entity.

If you want to load the related entity, you might as well just query it and assign it to the navigation property.

After setting the foreign key property on an entity, you can load the related entity if you want to using [explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit). eg

```
db.Entry(student).Reference(b => b.Department).Load();
```

Comment: Browne thats what i thought, but just wanted to make sure, since this was previously possible in mvc 4/5 using linq to sql...anyways thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

`SaveChanges` will not automatically load the relationship data unless context is already tracking the corresponding entity ([Change Tracking in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)). In addition to using one of the options to [load the related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) (for example the one suggested by [@David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) in his answer), following things will do the trick:

```cs
db.Departments.Find(1);
var student = db.Students.Find(9);
student.departmentId = 1;
db.SaveChanges(); // student.department will be filled here
```

Or even

```cs
var student = db.Students.Find(9);
student.departmentId = 1;
db.SaveChanges();
db.Departments.Find(1); // student.department will be filled here
```

Comment: the solution that you mentioned in the first code block is exactly the same as the one that i have mentioned, which doesn't do what I really want. It just saves student with the correct foreign key, but after SaveChanges() the Department object in Student doesn't get populated

Comment: @sj_7 sorry, during copy-paste one line got lost. See the update.