# How to get nested properties of entities after SaveAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

With EF Core, I have this entity

```
public class BankAccount
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Number { get; set; }
    [Required] public string BankId { get; set; }
    [Required] public string AccountTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required] public Bank Bank { get; set; }
    [Required] public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }

    public BankAccount(string name, string number, string bankId, string accountTypeId)
    {
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        Number = number ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(number));
        BankId = bankId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bankId));
        AccountTypeId = accountTypeId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accountTypeId));
    }
}
```

There are 2 foreign keys, `BankId` and `AccountTypeId`. Here are the entities:

```
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class AccountType
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class Bank
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

When I save the `BankAccount`:

```
await context.BankAccount.AddAsync(bankAccount);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How to retrieve the following nested properties:

> bankAccount.Bank.Name

> bankAccount.AccountType.Name

Something like :

```
return new BankAccountDTO
                    (
                        Id: bankAccount.Id,
                        Name: bankAccount.Name,
                        Number: bankAccount.Number,
                        BankDTO: new BankDTO(Id: bankAccount.Bank.Id, Name: bankAccount.Bank.Name),
                        AccountTypeDTO: new AccountTypeDTO(Id: bankAccount.AccountType.Id, Name: bankAccount.AccountType.Name)
                    );
```

Because in this case `bankAccount.Bank` and `bankAccount.AccountType` are null.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75008623/5045688

Comment: Ok clear for this part. It means that in every cases, for the post request, I need to retrieve the nested entities "manually". Where to place the logic? In the client or in the API?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Microsofts documentation regarding [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). It describes various ways how you can load data from other tables in your query, like using `.Include`.

Another thing to note is that you are using `.AddAsync`, [which probably not what you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addasync?view=efcore-7.0#remarks).